# How can I get an HTML option value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there and thanks for reading. I'm just getting started with JavaScript and I'm trying to collect an HTML option value as a variable.

I made a function that executes onchange that is supposed to collect the latest selected value and display that value in an alert window. I use console.log to see if the variable is set. It seems to be set to undefined. A pop up window does show up, but it's always displays the if statement text.

I swear I'm close to a solution but I just can't seem to find an example that matches what I'm trying to accomplish online.

HTML

```
<form>
    <select id="GameSeries" onchange="choose1()">
      <!-- Default Option -->
      <option value="">Select Game:</option>
      <!-- Art of Fighting-->
      <option value="AOF">Art of Fighting</option>
      <!-- Guilty Gear -->
      <option value="GG">Guilty Gear</option>
      <!-- King of Fighters -->
      <option value="KOF">The King of Fighters</option>
      <!-- Last Blade -->
      <option value="LB">Last Blade</option>
      <!-- Soul Calibur -->
      <option value="SC">Soul Calibur</option>
      <!-- Street Fighter -->
      <option value="SF1">Street Fighter</option>
      <option value="SF2">Street Fighter 2</option>
    </select>

  </form>
```

JS

```
//Attempt 2

var chsfirst;

function choose1 () {
    var chsfirst = document.getElementById("GameSeries").value;
  //ar chsfirst = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
  if (chsfirst = 'AOF') {
    alert("Art of Fighting"); }
  else if (chsfirst != 'AOF')  {
    alert("Not Art of Fighting"); }
};

console.log(chsfirst);

// Attempt 1
/*
function choose1 () {
  //first option event
  document.getElementById('GameSeries').value;
  if ElementById('GameSeries').value="AOF",
  window.alert("this worked!");
  //second option event
};
*/
```

Sorry if my terminology is off.

Really appreciate all the help.

Comment: chsfirst = 'AOF' should be changed to chsfirst == 'AOF' and use commented line to get the selected value

Comment: Additional to @Tej's comment, there is another thing. You don't need `else if` here. You can do it like;`else  { alert("Not Art of Fighting"); }`

Comment: get a linter http://jshint.com/ it will hope you figure out your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tips folks. I'll look into JShint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var chsfirst;

function choose1 () {
    chsfirst = document.getElementById("GameSeries").value;
  if (chsfirst === 'AOF') {
    alert("Art of Fighting"); }
  else if (chsfirst != 'AOF')  {
    alert("Not Art of Fighting"); }
    console.log(chsfirst);
};
```

```html
<form>
    <select id="GameSeries" onchange="choose1()">
      <!-- Default Option -->
      <option value="">Select Game:</option>
      <!-- Art of Fighting-->
      <option value="AOF">Art of Fighting</option>
      <!-- Guilty Gear -->
      <option value="GG">Guilty Gear</option>
      <!-- King of Fighters -->
      <option value="KOF">The King of Fighters</option>
      <!-- Last Blade -->
      <option value="LB">Last Blade</option>
      <!-- Soul Calibur -->
      <option value="SC">Soul Calibur</option>
      <!-- Street Fighter -->
      <option value="SF1">Street Fighter</option>
      <option value="SF2">Street Fighter 2</option>
    </select>

  </form>
```

You already made var chsfirst you don;t need to make it again just asign value.

Answer (score 0):

chsfirst === “AOF”

Or

if(document.getElementById("GameSeries").value.includes(“AOF”))

Comment: If it’s the answer you used, please check mark it:)

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator inside if condition. You should use Comparison, Logical  or Bitwise operators inside if condition.

`if (chsfirst = 'AOF')` should be replaced with `if (chsfirst === 'AOF')`